# Test class keeping the first constructor info as tmpvar1 but not using the new constructor variables

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am having problems with my test class.

When I initialize the class and run my method

```
qliUpdate1 scontroller1 = new qliUpdate1(new ApexPages.StandardSetController(qli1));
        scontroller1.save();
```

it works, however if I create a new class (to test with a different record type ) the test seems to keep the old info and does not test my second initialized class. The code is below, does anyone see a problem with it?

```
//Setting up the tests
//First run through (which will work)         
PriceBook2 testPBook1 = [SELECT Id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE Id = '01s40000000Eud6AAC'LIMIT 1];
        List<Id> testpBookId1 = new List<Id>{testPBook1.Id};  
        PriceBookEntry testPriceBookEntryItem1  =   [SELECT Id FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id IN : testpBookId1 AND ProductCode = 'M-PREM-SUPP-2' LIMIT 1];         
        Quote testQuote1 = TestUtil.initQuote2(testOpp,testPBook1 );
        QuoteLineItem testQLIItem1 = TestUtil.initQuoteLineItem(testQuote1, testPriceBookEntryItem1 , 10000);


    //Setting up for second run through 
    PriceBook2 testPBook2 = [SELECT Id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE Id = '01s40000000UyTVAA0'LIMIT 1]; //Bad way of doing this
    List<Id> testpBookId2 = new List<Id>{testPBook2.Id};
    PriceBookEntry testPriceBookEntryItem2  =   [SELECT Id FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id IN: testpBookId2 AND ProductCode = 'M-PREM-SUPP-REN' LIMIT 1];            
    Quote testQuote2 = TestUtil.initQuote2(testOpp,testPBook2 );
    QuoteLineItem testQLIItem2 = TestUtil.initQuoteLineItem(testQuote2, testPriceBookEntryItem2 , 1000);


Test.startTest();
//First run through (again this will work because I call this class and method first
        List<Id> tQuoteId1 = new List<Id>{tQuote[0].Id};
        List<QuoteLineItem> qli1 = [SELECT Id, Product_Code__c FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId IN: tQuoteId1];   
        qliUpdate1 scontroller1 = new qliUpdate1(new ApexPages.StandardSetController(qli1));
        scontroller1.save(); 

//Second run through, this one will run.. but in the debug will show that it is just running the first quote's Id and not Quote 2
        List<Id> tQuoteId2 = new List<Id>{tQuote[1].Id};
        List<QuoteLineItem> qli2 = [SELECT Id, Product_Code__c FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId IN: tQuoteId2];  
        scontroller1 = new qliUpdate1(new ApexPages.StandardSetController(qli2));
        scontroller1.save(); 

Test.stopTest();
```

the controller :

```
public with sharing class qliUpdate1 
{

    public PageReference save()
    {

        if(quoteId.Pricebook2.Description == 'This is the price book for maintenance renewals.')
        {
            saveRenewal(); 
        }            
        else //anything other than renewals
        {
            saveStandard();            
        }               
        return pr;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code posted , the following line is present :

```
List<Id> tQuoteId1 = new List<Id>{tQuote[0].Id};
```

Where is tQuote coming from ?

Comment: the quote coming from :  List<Quote> tQuote = [SELECT Id, Name,Pricebook2Id FROM Quote WHERE Name = 'JFTestQuote' ];